# jquery plugin issues with counting chars when returns are used

Tags: jquery, char, counter

I have a problem with jquery.charcounter.js its not counting returns as /r/n its counting them as 1 char instead of 3 or 4 here is the code is there a way around it

```
            if (el.val().length > max) {
            el.val(el.val().substring(0, max));
            if (settings.pulse && !p) {
                pulse(container, true);
            };
        };
```

Comment: IMO, it could be argued that `\r\n` should not be counted as two characters. What do you need the count for?

Comment: Because i need it for validation to limit a textarea to 1000 chars but if you add returns into the textarea it counts it as 1 but when it goes to the db it is really 2 or 3 depending on the browser

Comment: I get a db error when it the textarea is 1000 but it contains 4 or 5 returns in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with jQuery or even charcounter, the .length property is purely javascript.  As far as I know, \n is always counted as 1 character rather than two.  I'm not sure what issue you're running into from this, but you may want to read this post:

[String length differs from Javascript to Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462348/string-length-differs-from-javascript-to-java-code)

Comment: +1 I was about to post the same thing about javascript length.

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction , on the serverside i had to check whether the field was more then 1000 chars if it was the find and replace any \r\n with \n