# asking for a textarea's .length produces wrong result?

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a html form with the following code

```
     <td ><label>
 <textarea name="comments" id="comments" 
      cols="100" rows="3"
      onkeyup="illegal()" </td>
```

when the js function 'illegal' is called part of the code is

```
cm = document.form1.comments.value 
cl = cm.length
```

But what ever the string length is, the result is an additional 13 characters ?

can anybody help me please ?

Comment: I hope your real markup doesn't look as what you've posted here. Maybe there are `\r\n` that are taken into account?

Comment: have you used an alert to see what is actually in cm or document.form1.comments.value?

Comment: Maybe this explains it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462348/string-length-differs-from-javascript-to-java-code

Comment: Darin, no there is a line missing from the code , that does exist in my script

Comment: @Mick: can you edit the question and add that line?

Comment: -1 Question is misleading with wrong code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you have there is that you haven't closed your textarea, though I don't know that it would cause the particular issue you're seeing.

I tried the following simple page:

```
<html>
<form id="form1" name="form1">
<label>
 <textarea name="comments" id="comments"
      cols="100" rows="3"
      onkeyup="alert(document.form1.comments.value.length)" ></textarea>
</form>
</html>
```

It works fine -- every time you type, it pops up the number of characters.  Correctly.  I've tried it in Chrome and in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

On a textarea you should look for the html content of the textarea element not for the value itself.